# Windows does not read partition

Tags: windows-7, linux, partitioning

I have a linux formatted partition. I'm trying to open that partition inside windows 7. And shrink it so that I can have more space. But all the options except delete and help are grayed out. What do I do?
[image]

Tried ext2explore but it seems it can only perform a copy of the whole partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows does not support the filesystem that you used in Linux (`ext4`, I'm guessing) and does not know *how* to shrink it.

You will have to use [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) to shrink the partition.

Comment: can I convert the filesystem to fat or ntfs without harming the files? If its not possible, then can you recommend a software that can read individual files and back them up.

Comment: @soul: No. You will have to boot Linux (if you want, a LiveCD), make a backup, and change the filesystem.